# Django - Change the default error messages for a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I'm trying to create a simple ajax form with a validation summary so I can't have the error message 'This field is required' show up n times. What I need to do is replace these messege with **one** message: 'Some fields are required.'.

The documentation is really scarse with form validation and I can't find any examples on how to achieve this. I have tried to iterate through the *errors* attribute of *self* on the *clean* method but apparently I can't set that attribute.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the errors, but still need validation, why not simply return that ajax response `if not form.is_valid()`?

```
if not form.is_valid():
    self.ctx['errors'] = 'Some fields are required.'
    self.ctx['success'] = False
# or some such
```

Comment: While this is not what I wanted to achieve since there are other validations besides the required fields, this was the approach that I had to take.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you're saying now. There are other validations you'd like to show... Sounds like you'd have to manually filter the errors dict since each error is not aware of other errors.

Comment: What is `self.ctx`?

Comment: @iacopo any method of storing data (often called the "context" in django form terminology) for use in returning as a response. In retrospect, I should have declared an arbitrary dict or self.get_context_data() for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the template. The default template when using `{{form}}` outputs the the individual field messages so [create a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields) which doesn't e.g remove `{{ field.errors }}`

Comment: I am basically returning the error list via AJAX. There is not template rendering for the POST response.